# I did -T for rails new app but now i want the default test framework to be installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry guys as I'm quite new to Rails. What command can I input to the terminal to add test framework to my app?

I previously generated my app with the rails new appname -T option

Thanks guys.

Comment: add generators in your `application.rb` config file ([documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators))

Comment: I did, restarted my webserver. test folders are still not appearing for my models and what nots.

Comment: My question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644619/test-folder-does-not-exist-using-rspec where I want to install the default test framework. what command can I type into my terminal to effect this? Thanks again

Comment: maybe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325977/how-to-re-enable-testunit-in-rails-4-after-rails-new-app-skip-test-unit) can help you